# "Актуальный" — значение

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, смысл

Всё чаще слышу слово *"актуальный"* в значении *"действующий, действительный на данный момент".* На всякий случай напомню, что исконный смысл этого слова в русском — *"важный", "существенный".*

*Как вы считаете, насколько это допустимо и войдёт ли это значение в словарь или народ переболеет этим?*

Comment: Раз в английском есть такое значение, то считаю и в русском оно вполне допустимо. Более того — сам часто так употребляю. Вопрос о словарях нужно конкретизировать. Какие именно? Викисловарь, например, этот смысл приводит. И не только он.

Comment: Я имею в виду признанные бумажные словари и их электронные версии в Интернете, Грамоту.

Comment: А примеры можно? В "новом" смысле.

Comment: Пожалуйста! *Наверно, у неё нету его актуального телефона.*

Comment: Простите, что за калька с английского?

Comment: @Aer: значение, заимствованное из английского.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой нет — какие контексты могли послужить прообразом кальки? Actual problems? Почему именно с английского?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой позволю себе пояснить насчет "кальки". Калькой (словообразовательной) называется слово полученное **поморфемным** переводом с языка-источника. Механический перенос значения с одного языка в другой, о чем вы говорите,  калькой называться не может.  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: @Aer: может, не только из английского, но в первую очередь из него, — он же наиболее распространён в мире. Какие контексты? Вон я пример привёл про телефон.

Comment: @behemothus: спасибо, буду знать. Только не знаю, как лучше "кальку" переделать. Так что если поправите сами, будет хорошо.

Comment: @behemothus вы, верно, ошиблись: Артём совершенно точно употребил этот термин. Калька (семантическая) — это именно что появление нового значения слова N в языке Q под влиянием слова Z языка H.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой я про английские контексты, которые вы имеете в виду, говоря о значении слова actual. Actual problems? Actual phone number? Это всё очень некачественные с точки зрения английского языка контексты, англичанин/американец так не сказал бы. Значение actual в английском очень непросто понять, точнее говоря не значение, а то, когда это слово стоит употреблять, чтобы звучать "аутентично". И Макмилланы тут не помощники, увы.

Comment: @Aer - посмотрите, пожалуйста, определение "кальки" хотя бы в Википедии. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) Если не устроит, найду еще массу источников. А откуда ваше взято? Оно вообще простите, напоминает тарабарщину с четырьмя неизвестными.

Comment: А, я дал определение словообразовательной кальки, назвав её "семантической" - ну это я просто в широком смысле слово "семантическая" употребил. Суть-то никак от того не меняется. Калька - это процесс перевода, а не какого-то "влияния".

Comment: @behemothus "С е м а н т и ч е с к а я калька — заимствование переносного значения слова (род, грамматический термин ← лат. genus; тронутый ‘психически ненормальный’ ← франц. toqué, от toquer ‘дотронуться’; конёк ‘любимое занятие’ ← англ. hobby ‘то же’ ← ‘лошадка, пони’)" Краткий понятийно-терминологический справочник по этимологии и исторической лексикологии

Comment: @Aer да, вы абсолютно правы: чувствовать это слово как следует непросто и я не совсем прав насчёт кальки. Я имел в виду, что английские значения этого слова ближе к контексту с телефоном, чем изначальные русские "важный", "существенный", "насущный". Хотя теперь я понял, что был совершенно неправ и в английском вообще нет такого значения "действующий на данный момент". Так что даже не знаю, откуда тут ноги растут. Сейчас поправлю вопрос, спасибо!

Comment: @Aer - отлично. Примерно то же, что и в вики. К случаю, о котором  идет речь (контоминации, межъязыковой омонимии,  буквализму - как угодно назовите) никакого отношения не имеет. Вот здесь. Второй тип ЛДП - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8C%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *чувствовать это слово как следует непросто* - посмотрите ссылку в моем предыдущем комментарии.

Comment: @behemothus а, дошло: вы про то, что слово — интернационализм, и что контаминация, и т. д. Простите, голова другим забита :(

Comment: Бегемотус, посмотрел, интересно.)) @Aer: интуитивно я чувствовал, что 'actual phone number' — это неправильный английский, но, не конкретизируя, думал, что могут быть другие довольно похожие примеры. Но, как уже сказал, понял, что и близко такого нет. Но откуда-то это всё-таки возникло в языке (имею в виду наше значение)!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой да, конечно, — и ваш вопрос вообще классный и интересный :)

Comment: @Aer: отлично! Спасибо большое! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы чуть иначе определил через синонимы изначальный (в момент заимствования) смысл этого прилагательного в русском языке: *насущный, значимый в последнее время, злободневный*. Поначалу употребление слова ограничивалось мнимыми сущностями (*вопрос, метод, задача, тенденция, ходячая шутка*), но со временем оно стало использоваться для характеристики сущностей материальных, например, версии программы (в значении "*действующая, текущая*" или "*последняя из годных*") или документа ("*действительный в текущее время*"). Это представляется вполне *допустимым*. Общий русский смысл сохраняет **привязку к настоящему времени**. К счастью, до типично английского употребления (в значении "*имеющий место на самом деле*", "*фактический*" - в противоположность мнимому или кем-то утверждаемому) дело доходит только в небрежных переводах, искажающих смысл оригинала.  Повод для тревоги обычно возникает лишь тогда, когда что-то ненормативное воспроизводится в речи тележурналистов (с "актуальным" я пока не замечал такого - на фоне ставшего уже безнадёжно массовым "в-том-числе-нчества").

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Да, действительно до "фактического", "реального" ещё не дошло в обычной жизни (надеюсь). Уберу эти варианты. А что за "в-том-числе-нчество"?

Comment: Это я о некорректном употреблении выражения "в том числе" - как присказки и штампа. По словарным нормам оно до сих пор имеет _буквальный_ смысл и требует предварительного упоминания общего понятия, на которое ссылаются местоимением "то (число)". Речевые "безобразия" с этим выражением начали развиваться лет 10 назад, но как норма не зафиксированы.

Comment: <<ставшего уже безнадёжно массовым "в-том-числе-нчества">> - о чем это? В остальном полностью согласен.

Comment: Да, я понял, вспоминаю вашу реакцию на чьё-то неверное употребление этого выражения, просто не хватает самих примеров, чтобы это ярко осмыслить в очередной раз.

Comment: А я бы тоже хотел ознакомиться с примерами неправильного употребления "в том числе". Я несколько раз фиксировал совершенно дикое употребление его в значении "кроме того". (вспомнить не могу, а сконструировать не получается именно в силу дикости подобного).  Но это все-таки разовые случаи, они погоду не делают, да и по смыслу ваших обсуждений не похоже, что вы об этом.

Comment: Первый попавшийся пример (употребление вместо "в частности"): _Вопрос заключения мирного договора между Россией и Японией **связан в том числе** с обязательствами Токио перед Соединенными Штатами и другими государствами._ Это далеко не самый страшный случай ("мужчины и женщины в том числе"), но наиболее типичный.

Comment: Спасибо за пример!

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю свои два рубля.

"*действующий, действительный на данный момент*" - это, в общем-то, его значение во французском языке (или, по крайней мере, очень близко к нему):

> actuel
>   *adjectif*
>   1. PHILOSOPHIE Qui est effectif, réalisé (opposé à *virtuel, potentiel*).
>   2. Qui existe, se passe au moment où l'on parle. *À l'heure actuelle.*
>   3. Qui intéresse l'époque dont on parle. *Une grande œuvre toujours actuelle*.

То есть вариант 2.: "который(-ая,-ое) существует/происходит в момент, когда говорят".

Соглашусь с @Alex_ander о *допустимости*, но, разумеется, могут быть и исключения, когда это будет звучать ужасно или непонятно.

*В качестве анекдота:*
Какое-то время мне пришлось поработать во Франции, с коллегами-французами общались по-английски. Они часто ставили меня в тупик фразой: "Do you use this (название прибора, лежащего на столе, с которым я работаю постоянно) actually?"
Только много позже я догадался, что они используют "actually" вместо своего "actuellement", т.е. *сейчас, в данный момент*, и просто вежливо интересуются, нельзя ли взять этот прибор на время, если он мне вот прямо сейчас не нужен.

**Добавлено**

Поскольку *анекдот*, как выяснилось, желательно пояснить, добавлю пояснение в ответ.
Английское *actually* и французское *actuellement* (оба - наречия) - один из примеров "ложных друзей переводчика". Они означают в этих двух языках совершенно разные вещи. 
По-английски это кратко изложено здесь ["False Cognates: 'Actuellement' and 'Actually'"](https://www.thoughtco.com/actuellement-french-mistake-1369440).
По-русски о значениях и употреблениях *actually* очень подробно можно почитать на enacademic.com: [actually](https://translate.enacademic.com/actually/en/ru).

В частности:

> ... Actually также не используется для описания событий, происходящих
>   в настоящем, или событий, которые произойдут в ближайшем будущем.
>   В этих случаях употребляются наречные сочетания at present, right now,
>   right away:
>   The firm has no vacancies at present — У фирмы в
>   настоящее время (сейчас) нет вакансий;
>   We are very short of time at present — Нам сейчас очень не хватает времени; 
>   …

Источник: ["English-Russian word troubles"](https://word_troubles_en_ru.enacademic.com/22)

PS [Google Translate](https://translate.google.co.uk/?client=opera&sxsrf=ACYBGNSeK1UCE0f6yt4pymKUJ5kh3NXuCw:1570221996323&uact=5&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#en/ru/actually%0A) действительно выдает в последней строчке:

> в настоящее время - currently, now, today, presently, at the present time, **actually**

Не верьте глупой железяке и плохим словарям, из которых он это надёргал (они тоже встречаются).

**Добавлено 2**

Я посчитал нужным прокомментировать [этот ответ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/456262/181932), касающийся английского наречия **actually**.

*Я начну немного в обратном порядке, потому что эта часть ответа у меня готова. Потом, возможно, добавлю некоторые комментарии, когда найдётся время и желание.*

Реверсо - это действительно полезный ресурс, но, увы, и к нему применимо правило "глупой железяки" в том смысле, что мусор (ошибки) там есть. Ошибки создают люди, Интернет лишь делает их более доступными.

Собственно, сами разработчики ресурса об этом [честно предупреждают](https://context.reverso.net/translation/about):

> The examples are drawn from millions of previously translated texts
>   ranging from dialogues and official documents to multilingual
>   websites.
>   …
>   You will find some translations above the list of examples. They are
>   automatically calculated by our algorithms. We cannot check them all
>   by hand; they are only displayed for information purposes. Similarly,
>   there is not always an exact match between the search term and the
>   highlighted translation in an example.

**Разбор примеров из [Reverso](https://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/actually)**:

1

Only a few asylum-seekers actually remained in Moldova.
Лишь несколько просителей убежища в настоящее время остаются в Молдове.

Контекст:

22. Mr. SIDOROV (Moldova) said that, in the past year, his country had become a transit zone for asylum-seekers from the Commonwealth of Independent States, the Middle East and Asia on their way to Western Europe. **Only a few asylum-seekers actually remained in Moldova.** His country had acceded to the Convention relating to the Status of Refugees and the Protocol relating to the Status of Refugees in 2003; it had adopted the Status of Refugees Act in 2002; and it had set up a department for issues relating to refugees within the Ministry of the Interior and a reception centre for asylum-seekers. Financial assistance was provided to refugees in accordance with the financial possibilities of the State.

[Источник](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiV-6-s3IzlAhWOgVwKHf0XDSMQFjAAegQIAxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocstore.ohchr.org%2FSelfServices%2FFilesHandler.ashx%3Fenc%3D6QkG1d%252FPPRiCAqhKb7yhslztXd5Nnh5GF9yFH9jwvimHROxeNW8rZ281vIxoRtmPKc5YKYMd6NygDOBV9vZ3TcvcInVSppwzLjQ8Slwl%252FqAcGNz%252FAPIMUJMtIiRNQsBg&usg=AOvVaw3NYQbSkPt5wdPpoy2mH-W8)

Вывод:
Перевод неверный, но "условно-допустимый", поскольку не меняет основной посыл всего абзаца.

Комментарий:
Приведенный абзац выражает следующую мысль: в прошедшем году был поток беженцев через Молдову с целью попасть в Зап. Европу. (И хотя) лишь немногие беженцы остались в Молдове(, т.к. остальные проследовали в Зап. Европу), Молдова присоединилась к Конвенции и т.д., выделила посильные средства и т.п.

2

Most of the actually installed safety-belt systems represent emergency locking retractors.
Большинство из установленных в настоящее время систем ремней безопасности представляют собой аварийные запирающиеся втягивающие устройства.

Контекст:

B. JUSTIFICATION
Safety belts are broadly accepted as one of the major contributors to road safety. Buckling up is seen as an obligatory process after entering a vehicle by most of the car users, not only due to enforcement, but also due attitude. Wearing and handling comfort play an important role in increasing such a positive perception. **Most of the actually installed safety belt systems represent emergency locking retractors.** In the case of multiple sensitivity, strap sensitivity must not lock at an acceleration of less than 0.8 g and shall lock up at an acceleration of 2.0 g when measured in the direction of the extraction of the strap.

[Источник](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjV-K7i5YzlAhUTSxUIHTabCwQQFjAAegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.unece.org%2Ffileadmin%2FDAM%2Ftrans%2Fdoc%2F2012%2Fwp29grsp%2FGRSP-51-09e.doc&usg=AOvVaw1otErvBKbBjKtEsYprompO)

Вывод:

Английский для автора текста – не родной. Употребление *actually* здесь скалькировано с одного из европейских языков (например, французского или испанского). Правильно было бы использовать *currently*. Но перевод на русский тем не менее — правильный, так как переводчик понял, **что** автор на самом деле хотел сказать.

Комментарий:

Авторство документа: «Transmitted by the expert from CLEPA», [CLEPA, clepa.eu](https://clepa.eu/who-we-are/)

3

A draft immigration bill is actually pending before Parliament.
В настоящее время на рассмотрении парламента находится проект закона об иммиграции.

Контекст:

Article 2 (Policy of eliminating racial discrimination in all its forms)

12. Since the submission of the last Greek report and its consideration by the Committee in August 1992, the Greek Governments have made serious efforts for the elimination of all forms of discrimination in the Greek society through the adoption of concrete legislative or other measures aimed at promoting effective equality among individuals.  In this respect “vulnerable” groups within Greece, such as Roma people and their children, migrant workers, refugees and asylum seekers, and their human rights situation, are at the core of the concern of the authorities.  In addition, new measures have been envisaged in order to facilitate the integration of migrant workers into the social, economic and cultural life of the country.  **A draft immigration bill is actually pending before Parliament.**  The main lines of the proposed measures are described below.

[Источник](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwic4qno6YzlAhXKTcAKHQKdAy8QFjACegQIAhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocstore.ohchr.org%2FSelfServices%2FFilesHandler.ashx%3Fenc%3D6QkG1d%252FPPRiCAqhKb7yhsjiM0YseqozxfKWPHPzlS3zhB%252BHrX%252Buiw07DrhodmCeuG8%252FL%252BNPx%252FBIWBBfshDtUBvuw2HFjop0buK7AFzXJcZOyY2to0%252BsTJb%252BffuuQdB8v&usg=AOvVaw0wTMXEZqImEJALy7XL_OtE)

Вывод:

Перевод верен. Однако *actually* здесь не несёт в себе смысла «в настоящее время», и предложение переводилось бы точно так же, если бы *actually* было опущено.

Комментарий:

«В настоящее время» в переводе происходит от Present Continuous tense в оригинале. Наречие *actually* имеет лишь усилительную функцию. В целом, авторы абзаца пытаются продемонстрировать тем, кому текст предназначен (ООН), что они «приняли меры», «приложили серьёзные усилия» и настолько далеко в этом продвинулись, что черновой вариант законопроекта **уже даже** представлен на рассмотрение парламента.

4

These rules only apply to VMS actually.
Эти правила в настоящее время применяются только к ЗИС.

Контекст (оригинал на французском):

Par contre, les PMV sont plus souples, ils peuvent être mis en place puis enlevés, utilisés 
par différentes mains ... en appliquant quelques règles de base structurelles afin de garantir 
leur utilisation unifiée dans les différents centres de contrôle de la circulation. Donc, pour 
commencer, si nous voulons appliquer certaines règles à certains types de panneaux de 
signalisation routière, nous devons définir lesquelles.  **Ces règles s’appliquent uniquement 
aux PMV existants à ce jour.** Les panneaux à message variable peuvent clairement 
s’opposer aux panneaux à message fixe

[Источник](https://docplayer.fr/143593375-Conseil-economique-et-social.html)

Вывод:

Перевод с английского неверен. Перевод оригинала на английский – еще хуже.

Комментарий:

*ЗИС – это Знаки с Изменяющимся Сообщением (дорожные табло)*.

Тот самый «ложный друг» встречается ещё раз. Трудно сказать, человеческий это перевод или машинный, но «PMV existants à ce jour» (ЗИС существующие на сегодняшний день) каким-то образом заменилось на *VMS actually*, получилась «кривая» фраза по-английски, которую, как ни переводи, оригинального смысла уже не получишь (если не обратишься к оригиналу).

5

Only half of approximately 200 registered lawyers are actually practising.
В настоящее время в стране работают лишь 50% из приблизительно 200 зарегистрированных адвокатов.

Чуть отступлю от шаблона. Мгновенная реакция англичанина на эту фразу: «Yes, the rest are *actually* playing golf»

Контекст:

Не найден. Но на том же Реверсо находится испано-английский перевод:

Actualmente sólo ejerce la mitad de los alrededor de 200 abogados registrados.
Only half of approximately 200 registered lawyers are actually practising.

Вывод:

По ряду признаков испанское предложение это оригинал.
Перевод с испанского на английский – не мне судить. Настораживает «ложный друг», который в испанском таков же, как и во французском. [Здесь можно почитать об этом](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53835/using-actually-to-talk-about-the-present?r=SearchResults&s=7|30.4806). Но, возможно, смысл всё равно передан верно.

Перевод на русский... наверное, почти не пострадал (по сравнению с испанским оригиналом), опять же – не мне судить. Если же рассматривать перевод с английского (не видя испанского), имеем картину, похожую на предложение «про парламент»: «в настоящее время» - от Present Continuous, а *actually* передано с помощью «лишь».

**Общий вывод по результатам разбора**

Ни в одном из приведённых выше примеров наречие *actually* не несёт смысловой нагрузки "в настоящее время"/"в данный момент" и т.п.
Примеры являются либо результатом ошибочного перевода, либо ошибочного понимания *actually* автором текста, не являющимся носителем английского.

**Что касается "тезисов"**

Человек, разумеется, свободен в выборе точек зрения, подходов и методов, если они работают лично для него.

Я рассматриваю и комментирую этот текст с точки зрения переводческой профессии, к которой имею некоторое *(очень давнее и косвенное)* отношение. А настоящие профессионалы, если им попадётся этот текст, пусть меня поправят.

С этой точки зрения, ключевым моментом, вызывающим возражение, является мысль: "чтобы осмыслить, надо *перевести*.." и далее по тексту.

Всё ровно наоборот. Есть базовое правило, которое кратко можно сформулировать: *"Не понимаем - не переводим"*.

Многие ошибочно считают, что это требование невыполнимо, если вы не носитель языка - это не так. Просто надо затратить некоторое количество усилий, иногда значительное. И только **поняв** "мысль", выраженную в оригинале, можно попробовать выразить эту мысль, как можно точнее, в языке, на который переводим.

*..осталось лишь закончить здесь..*

**О словарях...**

Совсем кратко.
Есть два важных момента, касающиеся словарей:

1) В них есть ошибки и неточности.
В хороших - меньше, в плохих - больше. Поэтому необходимо пользоваться множеством словарей.

2) Нужно уметь правильно интерпретировать найденный в словаре результат.
Поскольку слово, данное вне контекста, "содержит в себе все возможные смыслы сразу", то нужно постараться понять, какой контекст имел в виду составитель словаря, когда ставил в список значений слова тот или иной "перевод".

Собственно, лучше, чем это изложено в этой статье, мне бы изложить не удалось никогда:
[Слово пользователю о словарях, или почему не все словари хорошие](http://www.norma-tm.ru/about_dictionary.html)

> Общеизвестно, что человек, далёкий от словарного ремесла, склонен
>   доверять словарю. О том, что в словаре может быть ошибка или
>   неточность, он подчас и не задумывается. А, следовательно, принимает
>   на веру словарные данные, даже если они в корне неверны или совершенно
>   устарели. В основе такого отношения к словарям лежит сформировавшееся
>   отнюдь не сегодня убеждение потребителя в том, что словари создаются
>   группами учёных, которые тщательно проверяют словарные данные,
>   скрупулёзно отбирают материал. Но так ли это?

Comment: *"actually" вместо своего "actuellement"* - не очень понятна соль "анекдота". В английском есть оба значения, второе, которое фаши коллеги использовали действительно весьма редкое. Тут надо пояснять, "где смеяться".

Comment: @Горевант Второе весьма редкое - это какое? Значения в английском примерно такие: [actually](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/actually). Смеяться уже поздно, но если попробовать пояснить.. Для англоговорящего это звучит что-то вроде: "Ты этим прибором, вообще, пользуешься?" (При том, что вся моя работа состоит в том, что я им "пользуюсь", и мы оба это знаем).

Comment: <<Второе весьма редкое - это какое?>> - это то, которое использовали ваши французы. actually - "в данный момент". Могу только констатировать, что французы знают английский лучше вас.

Comment: @Горевант (офтоп и чат, конечно, но) - а ссылку хоть какую в подтверждение, не? :) По-английски читаете? [Почитайте](https://www.thoughtco.com/actuellement-french-mistake-1369440).

Comment: Гугл-переводчик вам в помощь. Вы меня хотите убедить в знании английского с помощью пособия для изучающий французский? Однако...

Comment: Mes félicitations au français anglophone!

Comment: Послушайте, чтобы изложить мысль "никто не знает английский лучше, чем я" не стоило так долго мучить клавиатуру и поисковики. Что должен уясниить человек, пришедший на ресурс, посвященный русскому языку, уяснить со всей этой информации? Что все тексты, где actually надо переводить как сейчас, написаны плохо знающим английский? Ну даже если так, переводить-то все равно надо.

Comment: *«Yes, the rest are actually playing golf»* - тонкая ирония. Но разве она что-то доказывает в плане выбранной вами темы искоренения неправильного употребления слова actually в английском. Остальное -  "ниачом", и комментировать-то нечего. "все татары, кроме я"

Comment: *Dynamic overloading of private-derived generic class is obsolete actually* - не хотите спросить англичанина, что сие значит в его понимании? Источника, к сожалению нет, это мои конспекты многолетней давности, когда я пытался получить сертификат.  Вряд ли я бы эту фразу написал сам. Но абсолютно точно, что здесь "фактическое" значение ушло на второй план в пользу "временного".

Comment: @tum_  *Написан он не для того, чтобы с вами спорить.*  - ну знаете ли... А для чего, позвольте спросить, на ресурсе русского языка подобные пространные рассуждения?!

Answer (score 1):

Сразу скажу, меня сподвигла на ответ полемика вокруг английского значения.
Но коль уж решил ответить, то ответ даю по существу.

Я не вижу никакой беды в том, что ***актуальный*** используется в значении действующий, имеющий силу на данный момент.

Собственно, Кузнецов дает исчерпывающий ответ на этот вопрос.

> АКТУАЛЬНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -лен, -льна, -льно. [лат. actualis
>   действительный, настоящий]. Важный, существенный для решения проблем,
>   задач настоящего времени; насущный, злободневный, современный. А.
>   вопрос. А-ая задача, тема, проблема. Исследование, а-ое для экологии.
>   Шекспировские пьесы актуальны и сегодня. <Актуально, нареч.
>   Актуальность, -и; ж.

Тут можно только добавить, что представление о том, что актуальный=действительный совсем не противоречит подобному. Сравните с использованием в выражениях "действительный член АН", "(удостоверение) действительно до" и подобными. Здесь очевидно, что "действительный" вполне может означать "действующий", то есть "актуальный". 
Отсюда заодно получаем, что предположение о влиянии английского, если оно и имело место, то предопределялось не столько механическим переводом, сколько внутренней предрасположенностью самого русского языка к ад**о**птации (sic! "to adopt" - усваивать) значения.

английская часть перенесена в отдельный ответ.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99626/discussion-on-answer-by-behemothus---).

Answer (score 1):

Я воспользуюсь возможностью дать второй ответ на тему , которая из оффтопа превратилась в офф-спин. Знаю, что такой прием может вызвать шквал критики, но эта овчинка стоит выделки.

Я про английское значение.

"На защиту" выносится полтора  тезиса.

1. Английское "actually" в некоторых, вполне правильно построенных фразах, может и должно **переводиться** как "сейчас", "в настоящий момент".
2. (полтезиса) В подобных ситуациях надо говорить именно о переводе слова, а  не его значении, выраженном в толковых словарях языка-оригинала.

Все остальное - не более чем аргументация и примеры к этим двум. В том числе - экспромты, что естественно предполагает и возможные ошибки.

Про первый тезис - см. ниже.
По поводу второго поясню. Можно сколько угодно исследовать и анализировать исходный текст, но чтобы его осмыслить, его надо все равно **перевести** на русский, встроить в русскую фразу, осмыслить на русском. Поэтому правы те, кто говорят не о правильном значении иностранного слова, а те, кто говорит о переводе.

Перенесено из основного ответа.
//=====
И об английском значении. Горевант прав. 
Англичане, как изначально и русские, не разделяют значения "in act" на два значения - "действующий" и "действительный". И не противопоставляют их. 
Поэтому нельзя доверять обычным английским толковым словарям, где нет даже представительной подборки примеров. Хотя Вебстер вообще дает "in act" первым значением, и только вторым "in fact". Тут важно понять именно перевод, поскольку англичанин просто не почувствует проблем русского, он не знает, что в русских школах не проходят этого "второго" значения.

Есть очень хороший сайт для поиска подобных примеров.

https://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/actually

Вот что я нашел, не особо напрягаясь.

Only a few asylum-seekers actually remained in Moldova.
Most of the actually installed safety-belt systems represent emergency locking retractors.
A draft immigration bill is actually pending before Parliament.
These rules only apply to VMS actually.
Only half of approximately 200 registered lawyers are actually practising.

Я очень сомневаюсь, что здесь перевод, иной чем "в настоящее время", будет возможен.
Да, можно фыркнуть, что сайт опять не тот и это горе-переводчики наваяли. Но фразы-то существуют независимо от источника. И их надо как-то переводить. А я такое встречал в документации постоянно. Так что полностью поддерживаю мысль не верить "глупым железкам" и верить своему мозгу, свободному от вбитых догм. 
//===

Все обсуждения примеров и всего, что напрямую к "тезисам" не относится - отдельными вопросами, пожалуйста.

Артем, если не трудно, сформулируйте все, что еще не нашло разрешения, еще раз. Так будет проще и яснее.

Comment: Я хочу поддержать Александра в том, что эти примеры могут быть неудачным переводом с русского на английский, а потом эти неудачные варианты перевели обратно на русский, догадавшись, какой смысл был вложен вначале. Что не нашло разрешения? Честно говоря, не могу понять, о чём вы здесь: *Вот видите... Вы даже этих значений не знаете.)))* Что ripe — берег, а exact — существующий (одни из значений)? Да чем вы это подтвердите?! И выражения вашего не нашёл: ‘to write off ashore’. Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку, чтобы убедиться. Если оно действительно есть, рад буду пополнить свои знания.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *Я хочу поддержать Александра в том, что эти примеры могут быть неудачным переводом с русского на английский,* - Да ради Бога. По мне так єто вообще не предмет обсуждения, откуда такие фразы взялись. Но если вы как автор вопроса считаете сие информативным - то флаг в руки. Мне-то интереснее понять, как переводить, а не "левел-оф скилл" переводчика.

Comment: Нет, это я не для плохой оценки переводчика, а чтобы показать, что английская фраза не очень полноценная. А что про остальное можете сказать? Хотя бы на выражение это можете дать ссылку?

Comment: *‘to write off ashore’* - пока вот "сойти на берег — go* ashore" - https://classes.ru/dictionary-russian-english-Smirnitsky-term-2081.htm

Comment: *чтобы показать, что английская фраза не очень полноценная* - ну хрен редьки не слаще.  Ваше право.

Comment: exact - наверное я ошибся. ripe - уточню. Ну вот здесь есть https://wordle.ru/word/ripe к сожалению без примеров. у меня четкая ассоциация была с береговой линией. Где-то услышанная, естественно.  Возможно ложная, но коли уж в словарь попало... К сути моих тезисов это никак не относится.

Comment: Занятно! В двух источниках действительно написано, что это берег приливной реки или моря: https://www.definitions.net/definition/ripe и https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-noun-for/ripe.html, но ни авторитетных источников не нашёл, ни пометок, устаревшее это или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Этимология (истинное значение) этого слова — деятельный.

> Первоисточник – позднелатинский философский термин actualis «деятельный», который образован от корня agere – «действовать, делать».

Всё остальное — длинная цепь ошибочных использований. Глупо спорить о возможности или невозможности придать этому слову то или иное значение. Вы можете его использовать хоть вместо «кухонный», всё, что произойдёт, — очередная ошибка, которая не изменит ровным счётом ничего. Умные люди это слово не будут использовать.

Comment: Почему умные люди не будут его употреблять? Какая бы ни была этимология, в русском языке оно прижилось в определённом (другом) смысле.

Comment: Вспомните, как маленькие дети порою путают слова. Они называют корову — быком, а быком — корову. Мы тут же поправляем их и говорим, что это — бык, а это — корова, не иначе. То же случилось и в момент заимствования этого слова. Никто просто так не «приживается». Кто-то ошибся и... понеслась. А умный человек любит обозначать явления теми словами, которые для этих явлений предназначались. 
У слова «актуальный» есть множество разных замен, на все случаи жизни. Это не то слово, без которого не обойтись.

Comment: «Действующий, жизненный, животрепещущий, жгучий, острый, волнующий, злободневный, насущный, современный, своевременный». Пользуйтесь, дорогой Артём, не засоряйте русский язык иностранщиной. Всех благ!

Comment: Вы, видимо, хотели сказать "быка коровой". Согласен, что много вариантов, только "действующий" к ним не должен относиться.

Comment: Кстати, непонятно ещё, что Вы цитируете.

Comment: https://lexicography.online/etymology/semyonov/